# Find and Edit Text File

Tags: python, replace, vbscript, automation, find

I'm looking to find if there is a way of automating this process. Basically I have 300,000 rows of data needed to download on a daily basis. There are a couple of rows that need to be edited before it can be uploaded to SQL.

```
Jordan || Michael | 23 | Bulls | Chicago

Bryant | Kobe ||| 8 || LA
```

What I want to accomplish is to just have 4 vertical bars per row. Normally, I would search for a keyword then edit it manually then save. These two are the only anomalies in my data.

1. Find "Jordan", then remove the excess 1 vertical bar "|" right after it.
2. I need to find "Kobe", then remove the two excess vertical bars "|" right after it.

Correct format is below -

```
Jordan | Michael | 23 | Bulls | Chicago

Bryant | Kobe | 8 || LA
```

Not sure if this can be done in vbscript or Python. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why do you still have two `|` after 8?

Comment: Hi. In the example above, there should always be four vertical bars per row that separate each fields. There are instances that a field can be blank, like the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python or vbscript could be used but they are overkill for something this simple.  Try `sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(Jordan *)\|/\1/g; s/(Kobe *)\| *\|/\1/g' file 
Jordan | Michael | 23 | Bulls | Chicago
Bryant | Kobe | 8 || LA
```

To save to a new file:

```
sed -E 's/(Jordan *)\|/\1/g; s/(Kobe *)\| *\|/\1/g' file >newfile
```

Or, to change the existing file in-place:

```
sed -Ei.bak 's/(Jordan *)\|/\1/g; s/(Kobe *)\| *\|/\1/g' file
```

#### How it works

sed reads and processes a file line by line.  In our case, we need only the substitute command which has the form `s/old/new/g` where `old` is a regular expression and, if it is found, it is replaced by `new`.  The optional `g` at the end of the command tells sed to perform the substitution command 'globally', meaning not just once but as many times as it appears on the line.

- `s/(Jordan *)\|/\1/g`

  This tells sed to look for Jordan followed by zero or more spaces followed by a vertical bar and remove the vertical bar.

  In more detail, the parens in `(Jordan *)` tell sed to save the string Jordan followed by zero or more spaces as a group.  In the replacement side, we reference that group as `\1`.
- `s/(Kobe *)\| *\|/\1/g`

  Similarly, this tells sed to look for Kobe followed by zero or more spaces followed by a vertical bar and remove the vertical bar.

### Using python

Using the same logic as above, here is a python program:

```
$ cat kobe.py
import re
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = re.sub(r'(Jordan *)\|', r'\1', line)
        line = re.sub(r'(Kobe *)\| *\|', r'\1', line)
        print(line.rstrip('\n'))
$ python kobe.py
Jordan | Michael | 23 | Bulls | Chicago
Bryant | Kobe | 8 || LA
```

To save that to a new file:

```
python kobe.py >newfile
```

Comment: Hi, wow! Just a couple of lines of code. I'm not familiar with sed, is it something I can run in Windows? Thanks!

Comment: @JamesVici There are a variety of ways to install `sed` on Windows.  I know that it is part of the Cygwin, GNUWin32, and msys packages for example.  Alternatively, I just updated the answer with Python code.

Comment: You guys are keying by the name, remember he has 300,000 lines of names.

Comment: JamesVici:  Is @RandySchuman correct that we need to perform these changes for all names?  Or, do we do the changes just for Jordan and Kobe?

Comment: @JamesVici Oh, I read it again, it says just a couple of rows are wrong.

Comment: If it requires two bars to be between "8" and "LA", then my script will not work for this. Looks like I misunderstood and jumped the gun. I'm going to retract it.

Comment: Thank you John, appreciate your detailed tutorial and help. Thanks Randy as well, and Daewon. Have a great day guys! :)

Comment: Hi John, sorry, follow up question.. how do I get to automatically save the text file right after editing the rows? And is it possible to have it run in the background, without opening the file? Thanks again.

Comment: @JamesVici I have updated the answer with code, for both sed and py,  for saving the output to a new file.   It is not clear to me what you mean by "running in the background, without opening the file."  Would you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a code snippet in Python 3.5 as follows.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

rows = ["Jordan||Michael|23|Bulls|Chicago",
        "Bryant|Kobe|||8||LA"]

keywords = ["Jordan", "Kobe"]        

def get_keyword(row, keywords):
    for word in keywords:
        if word in row:
            return word
    else:
        return None            

for line in rows:
    num_bars = line.count('|')
    num_bars_del = num_bars - 4  # Number of bars to be deleted
    kw = get_keyword(line, keywords)
    if kw:  # this line contains a keyword
        # Split the line by the keyword
        first, second = line.split(kw)
        second = second.lstrip()
        result = "%s%s%s"%(first, kw, second[num_bars_del:])
        print(result)
```